# No RuntimeException in stack trace when implementing HttpHandler.handle() in Java

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception, httpserver

I am developing an application which has to serve some XML file through HTTP. For the HTTP server implementaion I use the com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer and I created a handler class which implements HttpHandler. The very weird thing is that I cannot get any RuntimeException from the MyHandler.handle() method. I put together a sample code to reproduce the case I am struggling with:

Server code:

```
public class HttpServerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpServer server;

        try {
            server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080),0);
            server.createContext("/", new MyHandler());
            server.start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HttpServerTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Very Important Exception from main");
    }
}
```

And the handler:

```
class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {

    public MyHandler() {
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange he) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("hello");
        throw new RuntimeException("Very Important Exception from MyHandler.handle");
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Very Important Exception from main
        at httpservertest.HttpServerTest.main(HttpServerTest.java:26)
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
```

So as you can see, I can get the exception from the main class main method, but I do not get anything from the handler method. Has anyone seen something like this before? Runtime exceptions should be in the stack track trace always.

Thanks,
Zoltan

Answer (score 4):

The most obvious reason would be that exception is handled internally.

Quick look into internal classes :

HttpServer that is created is actually extension (HttpsServerImpl) that wraps **sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl** The last one is the one you need to look into.

I find at least one catch that handles all exceptions(though I don't know if this one handles your exception, to much code to read) :

```
} catch (Exception localException) {
          ServerImpl.this.logger.log(Level.FINER, "Dispatcher (7)", localException);
}
```

Most exception in this class are handled by internal logger. And since RuntimeException extends Exception it is probably handled somewhere there.

Comment: It's a year and a half later, but I'm commenting on this because I'm having the same problem. Your explanation is good (+1 to you), but do you have any idea how to fix the problem (how to print the exception)? Or at least how to access the server logger?

Comment: One bad solution is catch all exception with try catch

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's just a matter of removing the `throws IOException` from the overridden handler, and adding a generic Exception catch clause that spans your overridden method body, like this:

```
class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {

    public MyHandler() {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange he){
        try{
               System.out.println("hello");
               throw new RuntimeException("Very Important Exception from MyHandler.handle");
        catch(Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your answer is useless, the OP's point there might be other exceptions that not known at the beginning and your method won't be able to catch these exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

A late response for a problem that also occured to me when I was looking for why some code just didn't execute at all and I didn't get any errors.

A simple possibility to get some debugging info and code line links:

```
class ChangeLevel implements HttpHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange t)   {
    

        try {
            // do stuff
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
            e.printStackTrace(pw);
            String sStackTrace = sw.toString(); // stack trace as a string
            System.out.println(sStackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```